# esx4 vmfs3 raid rebuild

Tags: raid, storage, vmware-esx, raid6, vmfs

I have a ESX 4.1 Server with a storage on RAID 60. After the rebuilding of the RAID the vmdk-files are not working in my VM. On starting VM I have this error:

```
Cannot open the disk '/vmfs/volumes/4a365b5d-eceda119-439b-000cfc0086f3/examplevm/examplevm-000002.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on
```

`vmkfstools -B /vmfs/volumes/4a365b5d-eceda119-439b-000cfc0086f3/` doesn't work.

I can't chown, chmod, copy this files. How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the VMWare logs. It sounds like your datastore is damaged. If this is the case and you definitely can't access the files, there is not much hope "fixing" it.

You can give the [Java VMFS driver/toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/vmfs/) or [vmfs-tools](http://glandium.org/projects/vmfs-tools/) a try - the latter would conveniently come with an Ubuntu LiveCD.

If you are lucky, you would be able to read your images off the disk and copy them somewhere else. If you are not, your only remaining option will be sending the disks to [KrollOntrack](http://www.krollontrack.com/ps211-virtualization-recovery/), paying an awesome lot of money and hoping for the best.